# Laravel - How to write Multiple conditions in where clause?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Actually my query is:

`SELECT * FROM company WHERE status<>$status AND type=$b1 AND type=$b2`

How to convert this in laravel?

I did this in laravel but it is not working:

`$data['Company'] = DB::table('company')->where([["status","<>",$status],
["type","=",$b1],["type","=",$b2]])->get();`

Please help me!

Comment: Try with this: `$data['Company'] = DB::table('company')->where('status','<>',$status)->where('type',$b1)->where('type',$b2)->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **whereIn** method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array:

> $data['Company'] = DB::table('company')
>                     ->where('status','<>',$status)
>                     ->whereIn('type',['$b1','$b2')
>                     ->get();

Answer (score 1):

```
$data['company'] = DB::table('company')->where('status',$status)->where('type',$b1)->where('type',$b2)->get();
```

Comment: use DB; in your controller

Answer (score 1):

You should use where method in 1 condition

```
$data['Company'] = DB::table('company')->where('status','<>',$status)->where('t‌​ype',$b1)->where('ty‌​pe',$b2)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\App\Company::where('status','!=',$status)->where('type',$b1)->where('type',$b2)->get();
```